# Protect a file against modifications in git merge

Tags: git, rebase

I have a Git repository that I have forked. Now, let's examine a hypothetical:

Suppose there is a file "versionFile.java" that exists in "fork 1" and another file "versionFile.java" in "master".

Now, suppose I am working in "fork 1" and I get a pull request from "master" (or some other branch). However, in no certain terms do I want "versionFile.java" to be overwritten or merged from any other branch. This is my file. I simply want to merge all other changes.

I want to "lock" this file. I don't want merges to be "interactive". I don't want to have to manually track and examine and rebase anything. I simply want to tell git that this file is mine. Don't change it. No matter what.

Possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged versionFile.java
```

You can resume normal operation with `--no-assume-unchanged`.

Comment: @JamesBarwick: It should be permanent until you stop assuming it's unchanged, as per above.